# When user has no votes in the profile page, link to relevant help center page not to "What is reputation?"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, help-center

Currently, when user never voted we see this in his/her profile page:

> [image]

The "votes" currently links to ["What is reputation"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) help center page which just explains reputation in general, not vote specific. It's already linked to when user has no recent reputation changes.

Can the link point to either ["Why is voting important?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) page or maybe [Vote Up privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That section now links to the "[Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)" page of the help center. Good suggestion!