# Show comment "scores" in activity tab on profile

Tags: feature-request, comments, profile-page, recent-activity

I was wondering if would be possible to show comment votes when viewing comments we've left in the activity tab.

For example, I often go to my profile and click on the Activity sub-tab (now 'All Actions') to find comments I've recently left. If I want to see how many upvotes the comment got, or any responses (ones that don't tag me specifically), I have to click the comment and go to the question. Since comment "scores" don't affect reputation, I'm not aware of any other way to check them.

While I realize there's no easy way to show comments that follow (is there?), I think it would at least be possible to show the number of upvotes beside each comment, just like when viewing the question/answer on its own page. Granted, that's the least of the two uses but still. Seeing your comment get voted up is a great feeling if nothing else.

Would this be a possible and/or useful feature to add?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it does seem to be a duplicate, but there's no real answer on the dupe, and that one's 5 years old. How should we proceed?

Comment: Leave this one alive (undeleted) but closed as dupe - you can upvote the original request and start a bounty, other than that nothing we can do. With thousands of feature requests, only handful ever get official response and even fewer actually getting done. We should be happy for those few, it's more than all other sites I know, who don't even give such an option. (suggesting feature requests like that :))

Comment: Wow, you spent all your repz, very noble of you. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard if it can get us the functionality, it was rep well spent.

Comment: That's not a trivial change that a dev can do in his/her spare time (that's how most smaller feature requests are getting done, [sample 1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152419/make-it-clear-the-op-has-the-final-vote-on-suggested-edits), [sample 2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209518/when-user-has-no-votes-in-the-profile-page-link-to-relevant-help-center-page-no)) so chance is very low. But who knows... :-D